# Images wont show in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, image, visibility

So,

My images are located in wp-content/themes/mytheme/images

Originally, when i converted my site from html/css the path looked like this:

```
<img src="images/myimage.png" alt="some text" />
```

That did not work and I have now tried two diffrent solutions:

```
<img src='<?php get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/myimage.png'>
```

and

```
<img src="<?php bloginfo(); ?>images/myimage.png">
```

Have i missed something? I am new to wordpress an php and would appreciate some help. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost had it.  You left off `echo`.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_template_directory_uri

Output the URI

```
<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>
```

The full result is:

```
<img src='<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/myimage.png'>
```

I recommend you use Drupal if you haven't gotten too far with WP already.  :)

Comment: How do you recommend one over another without even knowing the OP's needs? Are you saying Drupal is a better choice under **any** circumstances?

Comment: That worked! Thank you so much =) Also, thanks for the Drupal-tip, maybe something to look into. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
get_stylesheet_directory(). '/images';
```

/images/myimage.png">
This will return the images directory path in the currently selected theme, even if it's a child theme.

[Function Reference/get stylesheet directory](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_stylesheet_directory)

Comment: If i understand you correctly I should change the word "template" to "directory"?  May I ask you to write the full path please?